# Twitter style (stock) mention with Slate.js

Tags: javascript, editor, slate.js

I am building a note taking app and for text I use the Slate.js editor. Twitter mention also works with stocks like this [image]

It basically turns into a mention if `/\$[a-zA-Z]{1,6}/` is true. What I have tried is to use the `normalizeNode` callback to change if the regex matches, by deleting the text and inserting a new node at that location but so far I've been unsuccessful.

Slate.js also has a nice set of [examples](https://www.slatejs.org/examples/richtext) but unfortunately haven't found any of them to demonstrate what I'm trying to do. What would be a good way to go about implementing this feature? Am I wrong to assume it's through using `normalizeNode`?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this question when working on typed in emojis. For example, when a person typed `:smile:` we wanted the emoji to appear (a la Slack). The only differences with stock symbols and emojis would be the stock lookup and the usage of `Transforms.insertNodes` instead of `Transforms.insertText`.

The code below should be enough to help someone solve their use case. The key is `startIndex` and `endIndex` which targets the replacement.

Here's my solution:

```
editor.normalizeNode = entry => {
  const [node, path] = entry;

  if (!Text.isText(node)) {
   return normalizeNode([node, path]);
  }

  const emojiMatch = node.text.match(EMOJI_REGEX);

  if (!emojiMatch) {
    return normalizeNode([node, path]);
  }

  const [searchMatch, colonMatch] = emojiMatch;
  const { index: startIndex } = emojiMatch;
  const endIndex = startIndex + searchMatch.length;

  const [matchedEmoji] = emojiIndex.search(colonMatch).map(emoji => emoji) as BaseEmoji[];

  if (!matchedEmoji) {
    return normalizeNode([node, path]);
  }

  Transforms.insertText(editor, matchedEmoji.native, {
    at: {
      anchor: { path, offset: startIndex },
      focus: { path, offset: endIndex },
    }
  })

  normalizeNode([node, path]);
}
```